# How to use placement new in an exception safe way?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Suppose I have a `MyStack` class which exposes:

```
class MyStack {
public:

template <typename T>
T* Push() {
    Reserve(sizeof(T)); // Make sure that the buffer can hold an additional sizeof(T) bytes , realloc if needed
    auto prev= _top;
    _top += sizeof(T);
    new (prev) T();
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(prev);
}

template <typename T>
T* Pop() {
    _top -= sizeof(T);
    return return reinterpret_cast<T*>(_top);
}

bool Empty() const {
    return _bottom == _top;
}

private:
    char* _bottom;
    char* _top;
};

// Assumes all stack elements have the same type
template <typename T>
void ClearStack(MyStack& stack) {
    while (!stack.Empty()) {
        stack.template Pop<T>()->~T();
    }
}
```

There's a hidden bug here. Constructing `T` in `MyStack::Push()` could throw which would leave the stack buffer in an undefined state (the allocated space would contain garbage). Later, when `ClearStack` is called, it will attempt to reinterpret the garbage as `T` and invoke its destructor which could cause an access violation.

Is there a way to fix this bug by only modifying  `MyStack::Push()`? (the limitation is because this is an external code and we prefer to make minimal changes so it's relatively easy to update the library)

I thought about changing `MyStack::Push` to:

```
T* Push() {
    auto prev = _top;
    T t();
    Reserve(sizeof(T)); 
    _top += sizeof(T);
    reinterpret_cast<T*>(prev) = std::move(t);
    return prev;
}
```

But it looks bad and I'm not even sure that it doesn't invoke any UB (and also forces `T` to have a move constructor)

Is there a better solution here to protect against throwing constructors? (preferably a small change inside `MyStack::Push()`)

Comment: Is there a reason for storing `char*` rather than `T*`?

Comment: Yes, the template parameter is per function, not for the chole class. Therefore you can put in various types on this stack, loosing the type information along the way.

Comment: @DeiDei: Note that his `MyStack` is *not* a template; it has no idea which types are in it.

Comment: @MartinUeding: And being horribly broken along the way; see my answer for why.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Breaking the type system is never a good idea. I am so reluctant to break it that I forgot some of the reasons why it is so bad. Thanks for your answer, it brought back some of the horror that you create with classes this way.

Comment: Not directly related to the Q, but I do not see any reason to use reinterpret_cast with placement new:
return new (prev) T();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code:

```
template <typename T>
T* Push() {
    Reserve(sizeof(T));
    auto prev= _top;
    _top += sizeof(T);
    try {
        new (prev) T();
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(prev);
    }
    catch (...) {
        Unreserve(sizeof(T)); //release the memory, optional?
        _top = prev;            
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is really that your design is wrong. You're making a type that behaves a bit like `std::vector`, but it has no actual concept of "capacity". So when it `Reserve`s memory, it genuinely expects that `_top` will point to the end of the allocated storage after this process has completed. And therefore if it doesn't, the type is in an invalid state.

Which means that, in the event of an exception, you have to *undo* the call to `Reserve`: reallocating the old size of storage and moving the stuff in that storage back<sup>1</sup>. A more `vector`-like implementation has 3 pointers: a pointer to the start, a pointer to the first unused byte of memory, and a pointer to past the end of the allocated storage. This way, if you `Reserve` but get an exception, you've simply got some extra storage lying around.

<sup>1</sup>: FYI: what you seem to be trying to do most likely will not work. Or at least, not with most user-defined C++ types. Odds are good that your `Reserve` call allocates new storage and does a `memcpy` into it and never calls the destructor on those objects (since you have *no idea* what type they are). Well, that's only legal for objects for which `memcpy` is a valid action. Namely, TriviallyCopyable types. Yet your `Push` function has nothing to guard it against non-TriviallyCopyable types.

Not to mention the fact that if anyone had a pointer to the old object, every `Push` call will *invalidate* that pointer. And since you don't remember the types of any objects, there's no way to reconstitute them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use three-pointer implementation:

- `begin` points to the first element.
- `end` points to one past the last element
- `reserved` points to one element past the reserved space.
- `begin=end=reserved(=nullptr)` represents non-allocated container.
- `begin+1=end=reserved` represents filled container with one element.
- `begin+1=end;begin+4=reserved` represents container with one element and space for 2 more.

Then your Push method would look like:

```
template <typename T>
T* Push() {
    if(end==reserved)
        //relocate, ensure that begin<=end<reserved
    new (end) T();
    end+=sizeof(T);
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(end-1);
}
```